# How do I get the \paragraph's enumerated, but not the \section's

Tags: sectioning, numbering, sections-paragraphs

I need the `\paragraph{xxx}` command outputs "§ 1 xxx" but the `\section{Abc}` outputs just "Abc", no numbering. Any help? Thanks.

Comment: Should the sectional units associated to `\subsection` and `\subsubsection` be numbered or not?

Comment: Both `titlesec` package and `memoir` class might be helpful, see their (excellent) documentation.

Comment: the `\section` and `\subsection` must **not** be numbered, neither in the body not in the ToC. I'm using the memoir package indeed, but I can't figure how to manage that. If I set `\maxsecnumdepth{paragraph}`, then, how can I prevent the `\section`, `\subsection` and `\subsubsection` heading from show their numbers (in both the body and the ToC)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Normally `\paragraph` is defined using `\@startsection` which uses the counter `secnumdepth` to decide whether to number the unit.  For example, in `article.cls` you can find

```
    \renewcommand\thesubparagraph {\theparagraph.\@arabic\c@subparagraph}
```

and

```
    \newcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
                                {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}%
                                {-1em}%
                                {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
```

The first command numbers paragraphs as Section.Para, the second sets the formatting of the paragraphs.

You can patch these commands,  for example

```
\documentclass{article}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}         % Now sections are not numbered
\renewcommand\theparagraph{\arabic{paragraph}} % delete the section num from \theparagraph
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\paragraph{%
   \refstepcounter{paragraph}%   Manually stepping paragraph counter without consulting secnumdepth
   \@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
     {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}%
     {-1em}%
     {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\S~\theparagraph\space}} % Formatting the paragraph
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{First section}
\paragraph{First paragraph} Second
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! It seems that this will do the trick. But, will this show the paragraph number in the table of contents? It is not necesary, but would be very practical. Again, the section and subsection numbers must not be shown in the ToC.

Comment: Try, for example, `\renewcommand*\l@paragraph{\@dottedtocline{0}{7.0em}{4.1em}}`.  The first zero here tells TOC to put the paragraph sections into TOC on the 0 level

Comment: Thanks @Boris! I finally get what I wanted: The `\section` and `\subsection` must appear in the ToC without number but the `\paragraph` must be numerated, so I use `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}`. I got this with a little addition to the code you suggested, so now it looks like this.

Comment: `\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@paragraph{\@dottedtocline{0}{7.0em}{4.1em}}% Include paragraph as 0 level in ToC
\newcommand\Paragraph{% with capital “P” for distinction
 \refstepcounter{paragraph}%   Manually stepping paragraph counter without consulting secnumdepth
 \@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
 {1.5ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}%
 {-1em}%
 {\normalfont\normalsize\sffamily[\bfseries\S~\thechapter.\theparagraph\mdseries]\bfseries\space}
} % Formatting the paragraph

\renewcommand\paragraph[1]{%
    \Paragraph[\S~\thechapter.\theparagraph\space~#1][#1]{#1}
}
\makeatother`

Comment: Well, I can't include the proper format in the previous comment (this is my first time :) but I expect to be understandable.

I know it doesn't seem a clean solution, so if anyone can figure out something better it would be great.

Thanks guys, you're awsome.